# Implementing iPad General Setting Page

Tags: ios, ipad

So far I have customized the tableview and implemented the iPad General Setting Page. Below is the code for tableview which will change frame accordingly. But the issue is when I insert/delete rows or section in the tableview. My tableviewcell backgroundview (not cell) width get shrinks. Any idea what wrong am I doing here?

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        CGFloat inset =10;
        frame.origin.x += inset;
        frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;//The issue is in this line
    }
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if it is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple solution to achieve this. No need of customizing UITableView subclass. Just take the outlet of tableview and set the frame and change the color of backgroundview. like that below:-

```
CGFloat tableBorderLeft = 10;
CGFloat tableBorderRight = 10;
CGRect tableRect = self.view.frame;
tableRect.origin.x += tableBorderLeft; // make the table begin a few pixels right from its origin
tableRect.size.width -= tableBorderLeft + tableBorderRight; // reduce the width of the table
yourTableView.frame = tableRect;
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(239/255.0f) green:(239/255.0f) blue:(244/255.0f) alpha:1.0];
```